# How to make reusable examples in xml-format

Tags: xml, swagger

I'm trying to make some reusable examples of responses showed in xml and json formats

I' ve tried to write two types of response's example but there is a mistake

```
responses:
   '400':  
          description: Ошибки валидации запроса  
          content:   
            application/xml:  
              schema:  
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'  
              examples:  
                400wrongBodyFormat:  
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/400wrongBodyFormat'

examples:  
  400wrongBodyFormat:  
        value:   
          httpCode: 400
          httpMessage: Bad Request
          moreInformation: Body of the request is not valid according to json 
                           schema

schemas:
    ErrorResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        httpCode:
          type: integer
        httpMessage:
          type: string
        moreInformation:
          type: integer
```

I want to get smth like this:

```
<400>
  <httpCode>400</httpCode>
  <httpMessage>Bad request</httpMessage>
</400>
```

But getting this

```
{
  "httpCode": 400,
  "httpMessage": "Bad Request",
  "moreInformation": "Body of the request is not valid according to json schema"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the XML response example as text:

```xml
components:
  examples:  
    400wrongBodyFormat:  
      value: |-
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <ErrorResponse>
          <httpCode>400</httpCode>
          <httpMessage>Bad Request</httpMessage>
          <moreInformation>Body of the request is not valid according to json schema</moreInformation>
        </ErrorResponse>
```

You can also remove `examples` from the response and instead add property example values to the schema and have Swagger UI generate the response example automatically based on the schema.

```
      responses:
       '400':  
          description: Ошибки валидации запроса  
          content:   
            application/xml:  
              schema:  
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'  

components:
  schemas:
    ErrorResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        httpCode:
          type: integer
          example: 400
        httpMessage:
          type: string
          example: Bad Request
        moreInformation:
          type: integer
          example: Body of the request is not valid according to json schema
```